# Find where column matches more than one in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need results to have a 1:1 cardinality so I need to test if a value in COL1 exists more than once in COL2

```
COL1    COL2
A   1
B   2
B   2
B   3
C   4
D   5
E   5
E   5
```

Using Python (preferrably Pandas unless a better way exists), I want to see all rows where a value in COL1 has more than one match in COL2? In the example above, I want to know when COL1=B has more than 1 match in COL2 (i.e the cardinality in COL1 = B matches/joins with COL2 = 2 & also 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the rows that violate this condition, use `groupby` and check with `nunique`:

```
df[df.groupby('COL1').COL2.transform('nunique') > 1]
```

Or, with `groupby`, `nunique`, and `map`:

```
df[df.COL1.map(df.groupby('COL1').COL2.nunique()) > 1]

  COL1  COL2
1    B     2
2    B     2
3    B     3
```

---

If you want a mapping of COL1 value to COL2 values, you can use an additional `groupby` and `apply`:

```
df[df.groupby('COL1').COL2.transform('nunique') > 1].groupby('COL1').COL2.apply(set)

COL1
B    {2, 3}
Name: COL2, dtype: object
```

And finally, if all you want is the "cardinality" for > 1 COL1 values, use

```
df.groupby('COL1').COL2.nunique().to_frame().query('COL2 > 1')

      COL2
COL1      
B        2
```

Comment: Thanks, that was fast! This answers my question. I now realize that since I posed a minimalist question to the board, this code works for my state questions but I still need help with my full problem. How can I make this work if I have other columns that are either same or different values?

Comment: @Chris I understand. However, it would be great to avoid iterative debugging in the comments. If you have any follow-ups, it would be ideal to open a new question for it. Please consider accepting this answer, and we can help you with your follow ups as they come.